# Por que eu deveria usar getResource()?

Tags: java, resources

Em Java não é nada incomum ver códigos que carregam imagens, arquivos de áudio, XML e outra coisas de forma mais ou menos assim:

```
final ImageIcon programLogo = new ImageIcon("res" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "icon.png");
```

Entretanto, pelo códigos que eu andei lendo e pelo que eu andei vendo nas novas bibliotecas Java, um programador mais experiente faria isso:

```
final ImageIcon programLogo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/icon.png"));
```

As duas formas não chegam ao mesmo resultado: O root path do primeiro exemplo começa do root path do ClassLoader e o root path do segundo começa pela pasta pai do .class, mas a segunda parece ser mais "profissional", já que é o que eu vejo em aplicações e bibliotecas "famosas".

Mas eu não entendo porque o getResource é mais usado. Que vantagens ele oferece? Porque, em geral, eu deveria usar getResource()?

Comment: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icon.png")` ou `getClass().getResource("icon.png")` basicamente irão buscar pelo recurso mesmo quando sua aplicação já estiver empacotada... `new ImageIcon("res" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "icon.png")` não irá encontrar seu arquivo "icon.png", a não ser que ele tenha sido excluido do packaging e adicionado na mesma pasta de seu `.jar`.

Comment: @Josue, não seria legal transformar esse comentário em resposta? Por que, até 19 horas depois da publicação, é a única resposta disponível e explicativa para a pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em resumo:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icon.png") 
//ou 
getClass().getResource("icon.png")
```

basicamente irão buscar pelo recurso mesmo quando sua aplicação já estiver empacotada. Porém:

```
new ImageIcon("res" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "icon.png")
```

Não irá encontrar seu arquivo "icon.png", a não ser que ele tenha sido excluido do packaging e adicionado na mesma pasta de seu `.jar`

Esse é um erro muito comum de quem vai distribuir o jar pela primeira vez, não é uma questão de ficar "mais profissional" e sim a forma correta.

Para uma resposta mais detalhada a respeito, segue a fonte:

[SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java)

Comment: Upvoted e selecionada como melhor resposta porque é a única. E, parando pra pensar, isso é óbvio: Resources estão junto com o .jar.